# How can I iterate over a ProcessThreadCollection to access a property of each object inside the collection?

Tags: c#, loops

I have a simple loop that attempts to iterate over a `ProcessThreadCollection` variable

Inside the loop, I am trying to access a property of each object in the collection like so

```
foreach (var thread in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)[0].Threads)
{
    var threadId = thread.Id;   

    Console.WriteLine(threadId);   
}
```

However, I get an error stating the following

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Id'

If I do the following, I can access the `Id` property of an object within the collection

```
var threadCollection = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)[0].Threads;

var threadId = threadCollection[0].Id;

Console.WriteLine(threadId);
```

How could I change my loop so that I could access the `Id` property of each object in the `ProcessThreadCollection`?

Comment: change "var thread " to "ProcessThread thread"

Comment: Have you tried replacing `var thread` with `ProcessThread thread`? Sometimes the compiler doesn’t infer the type you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Process.Threads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.threads?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_Threads) property returns [`ProcessThreadCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processthreadcollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) which does not implement generic [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2). Instead, it derives from [`ReadOnlyCollectionBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.readonlycollectionbase?view=netframework-4.7.2), which in turn implements non-generic [`ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Because of all that, when you defined your loop using `var` the type of the loop variable `thread` is inferred to be `object`.

You can work around that in two ways:

Either explicitly specify the type:

```
foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)[0].Threads)
```

or call `Cast<ProcessThread>`:

```
foreach (var thread in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)[0].Threads.Cast<ProcessThread>())
```

Both of these will make the compiler realize `thread` is of type [`ProcessThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processthread?view=netframework-4.7.2) and not `object` and will give you access to all the properties of that type, including `Id`.